# Rotation without distortion using Matrix3D

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, rotation, scale, stage3d

How to assign a value to Matrix3D rotation about the axis Z. (li "rotation")?

The position and size are calculated correctly, but after the addition of rotation, the image is stretched.

I tried two method to rotation:

```
_positionMatrix.identity();
var v3:Vector.<Vector3D> = new Vector.<Vector3D>(3);
v3 = _positionMatrix.decompose();
v3[0].incrementBy(new Vector3D( x, y, 0 ));// x, y, z
v3[1].incrementBy(new Vector3D(0,0,-rotation*Math.PI/180)); // rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ
v3[2].incrementBy(new Vector3D(width,height,0)); // scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ
_positionMatrix.recompose(v3);
```

And:

```
_positionMatrix.identity();
_positionMatrix.appendScale(width,height,1);
_positionMatrix.appendTranslation(x,y,0);
_positionMatrix.appendRotation(-rotation,Vector3D.Z_AXIS );
```

But the effect is identical:

[image]

I find that "PerspectiveProjection" class can help, but cant to understand how to use it with rotation about the axis Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, its true, my perspective Projection matrix was "bad". 
This code works perfectly:

```
    private var _vertexData:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[
        0,0,0, 0, 0, 0, 1,// x, y, z, r, g, b,a
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 1, 0,0, 0, 0,1
    ];



    var perspectiveProjectionMatrix:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
    var scaleX:Number = 2.0 / _stage.stageWidth;  // 2.0 / 500
    var scaleY:Number = -2.0 / _stage.stageHeight; // -2.0 / 375
    perspectiveProjectionMatrix.copyRawDataFrom(
            new <Number>[
                scaleX, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, scaleY, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
            ]
    );
    var modelViewMatrix:Matrix3D = trs(stage.stageWidth/2,stage.stageHeight/2, _rotation*Math.PI/180, _width*_globalScaleX, _height*_globalScaleY );
    var resultMatrix:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
    resultMatrix.prepend(perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
    resultMatrix.prepend(modelViewMatrix);
    _context.setProgramConstantsFromMatrix(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX, 0,resultMatrix , true);
```

Where "trs" is:

```
public function trs( tx:Number, ty:Number, rotation:Number, xScale:Number, yScale:Number ):Matrix3D {

var data:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 1];

var sin:Number = Math.sin( rotation );
var cos:Number = Math.cos( rotation );
data[0] =  cos * xScale;
data[1] =  sin * xScale;
data[4] = -sin * yScale;
data[5] =  cos * yScale;
data[12] = tx;
data[13] = ty;


var matrix:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
matrix.copyRawDataFrom(data);
return matrix;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For start, if you have such a problem - try to eliminate matrix transforms one by one until you find which matrix is a "bad" one. For example, what will happen if you store only one transformation - scale or translation or rotation?
In your example I can't see any criminal, so the problem is further in code. I can assume that your projection matrix is wrong. Can you provide it? How do you apply final matrix to an object?